# Server Mainboard ASRock EP2C602 only detect half of RAM

Tags: memory, motherboard, xeon

I've been googling for several days but I can't really find a solution to my problem.

My mainboard ASRock EP2C602 with two CPUs Xeon 2670 only detects half of the RAM.

I have installed 2 x 8GB G.SKILL "F3-10666CL9D-8GBRL". In BIOS and in Windows 10 it only shows 8GB installed.

I also tested 2x "Kingston 99U5471‑002.A01LF" which has 4GB each. But again each module is detected with 2GB per module.

In total I have 12GB instead of 24GB.
From the website both RAMs are not in the supported list. 
https://www.asrockrack.com/general/productdetail.asp?Model=EP2C602#Memory
My question is could this be the reason or is it rather a mainboard defect?
All modules worked on other mainboards.

I also read about RAM mirroring functions on server mainboards where then it keeps half RAM as backup which then would makes sense. But I checked the BIOS and in my understanding it should be disabled.

[image: HWinfo Screenshot of RAMs]

Has anyone ever had the same problem?

Comment: Are you installing them in the correct slots using the correct memory channel configuration?  Does this motherboard require ECC memory by chance?  These modules single or double sided?

Comment: If you've tested all the configurations: Have you reseated the CPUs by chance? Sometimes the memory controllers on the CPU aren't functioning correctly because there's a loose.

Comment: @NatsuKage: Yes I removed and reinstalled both CPUs already. But still the same. I also played with the RAM voltage from 1.5V to 1.65V in 0.5V steps, but no change.

Comment: @Ramhound: from GSKILL website : Memory Type 
DDR3

Multi-Channel Kit Dual Channel Kit
Tested Speed 1333MHz

Tested Latency
9-9-9-24-2N

Registered/Unbuffered
Unbuffered

Error Checking
Non-ECC

SPD Speed
1333MHz I cannot say if these is single or double sided

Comment: @cekar - You can determine if they are single or double sided by looking at the modules.  You have not specified what slots you have used.  You understand that the slots are mirrored though?  *I suspect you simply don't have enough of the slots filled with modules and you are running into memory channel configuration issues.*

Comment: There are several variations of that board, post the entire model number please.

Comment: @Moab:  I know but the model I have is the one with only "EP2C602"

Comment: @Ramhound: I will check the used slots tomorrow. What do you mean with "You understand that the slots are mirrored though? " I don't really understand mirroring.. I can also post a picture of my BIOS settings

Comment: @Ramhound -  The Kingston 4GB RAM have chips installed on both sides of the circuit board. For the GSkill 8GB I cannot say as they are covered in metal housing (cooler?). The board has 8 RAM slots: For CPU 1 it s called DDR3_A1, .._B1, .._C1, .._D1. I used C1/D1 with the Kingston modules. CPU2 has E1/F1/G1/H1, there I used E1/F1 with the GSKILL modules.

Comment: The slots are mirrored.  You have 8 slots for each CPU.  The manual for your motherboard will specify everything you need to know.  Why did you use C1 and D1 instead of A1 and B1?

Comment: You need to determine if the modules are single or double-sided.  "A single memory module should be installed in the blue socket." because it does make a difference.  You need to fill the correct slots in order.  *The reason your system is not detecting the correct amount of memory is your not installing them in the correct slots.*  What I mean by slots are mirrored, on a dual CPU socket motherboard, is well documented.  The documentation on that motherboard isn't very good.  **Your memory not being on the memory QVL isn't an issue.**

Comment: sorry for the confusion i messed things up. My board has in fact only 8 slots in total, 4 for each CPU, as it is the smallest model. But I found now the specs of e.g. Kingston 99U5471‑002.A01LF which is also named on the label as KVR1333D3N9K2/4G and 4G is only the ram amount of the kit (2 modules). My failure was that I had the GSKILL (2 x 4GB) tested on the other computer and thought it was the Kingston. Means the GSKILL "8GB" is only per Kit as well as Kingston "4G" is also not per module but for two rams. Sorry my big fault. But thanks for all your support.